Conditional Formatting for line chart in Power BI

Here I'm using line chart in PowerBI, including Plan vs Actual value. If Actual value is greater than the Plan value Line color need to change to Green and If Actual value is less than the Plan value Line color need to change to red. But After updating Power BI version, the conditional formatting option is disabled. See in the image. How to do Conditional formatting in this case.

For line chart, we can't add conditional formatting on it.
You can do that on clustered column chart. However, you can only add one measure in the y-axis field.
You can create a measure
Measure = sum('Table'[actual])-sum('Table'[plan])

then set up the conditional formatting

at last, you can the chart to line chart

As you can see, we can only set up the color for marker. We can't do it for line.
